# Hide svc side in web application using SoapCore library

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, soapcore

I  have simple structure in my web application.
[image]

Is there any chance to hide a wsdl source in url https://localhost:7189/Service.svc to keep it unvisible from users?
[image]

I tried to create web.config and enter there some settings which I found but this not gave me expected results.

**Solution:**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<BookService>(new Action<SoapCoreOptions>(CreateBookServiceEndpoint));
});

void CreateBookServiceEndpoint(SoapCoreOptions target)
{
    target.HttpGetEnabled = false;
    target.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
    target.Path = "/BookService.svc";
    target.EncoderOptions = new SoapEncoderOptions[] { new SoapEncoderOptions() };
    target.SoapSerializer = SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer;
}
```

Comment: Ah, the good ol' security through obscurity. Why don't you take care of authentication and authorization?

Comment: https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/blob/320496225e6f1aee9faf54acd7c636fec6f886f9/src/SoapCore/SoapEndpointMiddleware.cs#L100) you can't issue GET requests when `HttpsGetEnabled` or `HttpGetEnabled` are false (for HTTPS/HTTP requests respectively), so something like this:

```
.UseSoapEndpoint(..., options => 
{
    HttpGetEnabled = false,
    HttpsGetEnabled = false,
});
```